# How do you hook up wifi to it? I keep trying and it will not work

Tags: wifi, internet

When ever I try it works until I get to the web browser. I have tried 4 times and it did not work. I have a B+ model. I have tried a linksys adapter. Could someone please help me!

Comment: You should describe in detail exactly *what* you tried 4 times.

Comment: @goldilocks I kept changing the interfaces folder one time I typed `wpa-psk="MY WIFI passcode` thanks

Comment: This is not enough information for anyone but a psychic  to help you and they are completely useless on computers. Which adapter are you using? Are you following a set of directions? have you read  how to file a bug report?

Comment: @goldilocks I am using a Linksys adapter. I am following a set of directions and I am new to the pi so I do not know how to file a bug report.

Comment: *What* Linksys adaptor are you using? There are hundreds, and even the same model number can have different (and incompatible) hardware with different versions.

Answer (score 2):

From the command line, try:

```
ip link
```

This should include an entry for a `wlan0`.  If not, have [a look here](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) and see if you can find mention of the adapter.  You can possibly also get the exact chipset with `lsusb`.

If it does show up, shut down networking with `sudo service networking stop`.  Create a file like this:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="Your SSID"
    psk="Your passphrase"
}
```

Include the quotes.  Call it `wpa.conf`.  Now:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo wpa_supplicant -c wpa.conf -i wlan0
```

Leave that running in the foreground; it should be clear it has contacted the WLAN, which might take 5-10 seconds.  Now from another shell:

```
sudo dhclient -r
sudo dhclient -v wlan0
```

Within about 30 seconds it should have told you you have a lease and an IP number, then it will go to the background and return the command line.  Check with `ip addr`; you should see wlan0 listed with that IP address.

---

If all this works but you don't get a lease, the adapter is almost certainly working -- just either it is not reaching a router, or the router is not willing to issue it an IP address.  That could be because of:

- Unusual configuration of the router.
- Typo in your wpa.conf.
- The network is not actually encrypted, i.e., doesn't use WPA.

In the later case, don't use `wpa_supplicant`; instead, use `sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid [your essid]`.  If the network is encrypted but you can configure the router, you might try turning WPA off temporarily (i.e., leave the network open) and try the same thing with `iwconfig`.

If none of these seems to be the issue, try `sudo iw scan wlan0`.  This will take a few seconds and will spit a list of all ESSIDs in the area -- obviously this should include yours.

Comment: thank you but I did not get to work the error message I got was `No working leases in persistent database - sleeping`

Comment: Well, that's good in the sense that the adapter is almost certainly working properly.  It means it is not being issued an IP by your router.  I've added a few things about this at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up fiddling with config files and difficult hardware, because this solution is cheaper and stress-free:

1. Get a [Miniature WiFi (802.11b/g/n) Module](https://www.adafruit.com/product/814). Many places sell these, and they are cheap. There are many lookalikes, but it *must* have a Realtek RTL8188CUS chipset in it.
2. Plug your Raspberry Pi into a monitor, and power it up with the wifi module installed. This may require a USB hub.
3. Use the [WiFi Config](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-raspbian) tool on the desktop.

The settings from the WiFi Config GUI are remembered across reboots, and it starts wifi on boot so you can do command-line things with ease.

Comment: The best place to start is definitely a chipset that is known to work (+1). RTL8188CUS isn't the *only* one, however (and pay attention, because the RTL8188 *EUS* is apparently more problematic).  Watch out since some adapter manufacturers can change the chipset (which they don't make themselves) without changing their own model number.  There's no way to tell that in the store, but it should show up via `lsusb`.  A good idea is to buy from somewhere reasonably close that will take undamaged stuff back within a week no questions asked. Note you shouldn't need a power hub with the A+/B+.